# Jekyll iterate over custom folder

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll and have a custom folder called `docs` with this structure:

[image]

The folder is organized as nested categories, but from what I understand from [this pull request](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6331) I can only have one extra level if I use `collections_dir` like this:

```
collections:
  js:
    output: true
  ruby:
    output: true
collections_dir: docs
```

What I want is to be able to iterate through all the files under the `docs` folder in order to create a search index for [simple-jekyll-search](https://github.com/christian-fei/Simple-Jekyll-Search).

I need to change `site.pages` here for something that iterates on the `docs` folder but I don't know how I can do that and if I can do it in a way in which I don't need to define a `.yml` file listing all the files on the folder myself.

```
---
layout: null
---
[
  {% for page in site.pages %}
   {
     {% if page.title != nil %}
        "title"    : "{{ page.title | escape }}",
        "url"      : "{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}",
        "date"     : "{{ page.date }}"
     {% endif %}
   } {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all of your collections in Jekyll and then access the documents/files within each of those collections. See the Jekyll docs on [iterating over collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#collections) and [accessing their documents](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#documents).

So you'd just have to slightly tweak what you've got there to be something like:

```
---
layout: null
---
[
  {%- for collection in site.collections %}
  {%- for page in collection.docs -%}
   {
     {%- if page.title != nil %}
        "title"    : "{{ page.title | escape }}",
        "url"      : "{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}",
        "date"     : "{{ page.date }}"
     {% endif -%}
   }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
  {%- endfor -%}
  {% endfor -%}
]
```